# Java extends from class with <class name>

Tags: java, android, class, extend

Can you explain what is the meaning of  in the below code snippet

```
public class NoteAdapter extends  ArrayAdapter<Note>{

}
```

In my example Note is java class.

Comment: Please read basic [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means `Note adapter` inherits from `ArrayAdapter` which is a generic class.The generic class ArrayAdapter accepts an argument of type `Note`.To understand more visit the topic `Generics in java`